# Fail Azure DevOps pipeline .NET Core CLI test task when no tests are found

Tags: azure-pipelines, dotnet-cli

Given a [.NET Core CLI test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#test), specifically `DotNetCoreCLI@2`,
that is expecting to discover tests, how can the task be configured to fail when no tests are discovered?

With the older [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) there were options for specifying this, which is what I'm basing this expectation on.

```
    failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
    minimumExpectedTests: '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we cannot set the task itself to make the task/pipeline fail when it cannot find the file.

For a workaround:

You could use the **Build Quality Checks task**  from [Build Quality Checks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks).

This task can scan all set tasks and check warnings. If the number of warnings is greater than the set upper limit, the pipeline will fail.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @kevin-lu-msft. Using the build quality check extension sounds like a good idea; however, I cant ever seem to be warning free due to tooling issues. Ex https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10839 open for 2 years, https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9186 still emitting warnings, etc. Though maybe a code coverage option might work for me. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Except for similar workarounds, there is currently no out-of-the-box functionality (dotnet test task)